# Wasp? Wicked looking bug

Tags: species-identification, entomology, wasps

Saw this bug this morning in Colorado. Looks like a giant wasp.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9):

That is a horntail, family Siricidae. https://www.insectimages.org/browse/taxthumb.cfm?fam=455
They are a family of sawflies. Not technically wasps, but they are Hymenoptera.

Answer (score 8):

Yeah, she looks dangerous doesn't she. However, the 'stinger' is used for ovispositing eggs in wood. These wasps do not sting.

This species is called **Pigeon Tremex Horntail**, *Tremex Columba*.

Nice pictures and very interesting information on the website below, however the images have copyrights, so I can't include them here.

http://bugeric.blogspot.com/2012/09/wasp-wednesday-pigeon-tremex-horntail.html?m=1

Comment: I haven't formally asked for a species identification (maybe I should?), but you may find this of interest and potentially amenable to an additional answer: [Why do wasps have "wasp waists"? What's been optimized?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/113738/27918)

Comment: Yes, beautiful tremex!