# What are the three dots (eyes?) on the top of this wasp's head? What species might it be?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, physiology, morphology

I photographed these (unidentified) wasps on a sunny but cool winter day in northern Taiwan because they were conspicuously hanging out on a hand railing and had much lighter coloring than I'd ever seen before.

But after I took the time to look at a close-up I realized "Wow, this wasp has three dots on the top of it's head!"

If it was a spider I'd assume they were eyes, but like many insects these wasps already have to large wrap-around eyes that extend towards the top of the head already?

**Question:** What are the three dots (eyes?) on the top of this wasp's head?

[image: wasps in December, northern Taiwan]

[image: wasps in December, northern Taiwan]

[image: wasps in December, northern Taiwan] click for full size

Comment: companion question: [Why do wasps have "wasp waists"? What's been optimized?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/113738/27918)

Comment: This is like the mud dauber wasp

Answer (score 7):

I don't know what species this is but a lot of bees and wasps have those three dots on their head.  They are sort of eyes, but they can't actually make out images.  They basically just detect light above the wasp's head.  By having three there in a triangular configuration, the wasp can determine the direction of any shadow that appears overhead, like a bird swooping down for a snack.

- [University of Houston - What Bees See](https://engines.egr.uh.edu/episode/2877)
- Wikipedia: [Simple eye in invertebrates; Dorsal ocelli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_eye_in_invertebrates#Dorsal_ocelli)

Comment: Neat. We often forget as mammals with a paltry two eyes that in other creatures, different eyes may have different purposes and be more highly specialized.

Comment: If I recall, these might be horizon sensors or sky polarization compasses.